# PyQt: Changing cursor when hovering a button

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to make a button (or any other Qwidget), That will change users cursor when hovered.

So for instance, when i hover QPushButton, it will change cursor from Arrow to Pointing Hand.

I am using Qt Style Sheet, so i'm not entirely sure, but is there any way to do something like that there?, should look something like this:

```
btn.setStyleSheet("#btn {background-image: url(':/images/Button1.png'); border: none; }"
"#btn:hover { change-cursor: cursor('PointingHand'); }
```

Note: Code above is for example, second line will have no functionality at all.

---

However, if not, if there any other way i can achieve this?

Answer (score 19):

For anyone who wants to achieve this in PyQt5, this is how I managed to do it. Let's say you have a button and you want your cursor to change to the 'PointingHandCursor' when you hover over the button.
You can do it with `your_button.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))`. For example:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QPushButton, QLabel, QProgressBar, 
    QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtGui import QCursor

import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.title = "your_title"

        self.screen_dim = (1600, 900)

        self.width = 650
        self.height = 400

        self.left = int(self.screen_dim[0]/2 - self.width/2)
        self.top = int(self.screen_dim[1]/2 - self.height/2)

        self.init_window()

    def init_window(self):
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('path_to_icon.png'))
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setStyleSheet('background-color: rgb(52, 50, 51);')

        self.create_layout()

        self.show()

    def create_layout(self):
        self.button = QPushButton('Click Me', self)
        self.button.setCursor(QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    App = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Very nice, you wrote a self-contained code snippet to show the functionality!

Comment: Nice... Works Perfectly

Comment: Appreciate showing all the necessary imports as well.

Answer (score 5):

Use `QWidget.setCursor (self, QCursor)`

http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#setCursor

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#cursor-prop

Comment: How can i set it to pointing hand cursor? I couldn't find it anywhere in documentary.

Comment: Hey come on, RTFM... On the second link, click on "list of predefined cursors objects"...

Comment: `btn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))`, i tried this, it would open without any errors, but cursor would only show once, do i need to loop this or something?

Answer (score 0):

For Pyqt6 you can use this code:

```
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt6.QtGui import QCursor
closeBtn = QPushButton("X")

closeBtn.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.CursorShape.PointingHandCursor))
```